# Can this problem be posed in terms of Probability?

Tags: probability

A photographer takes a picture of his vehicle's instrument panel, and later realized that the odometer reading == his zip code. Upon making this observation, he asks (figure of speech, really), "What are the odds of that?"

A friend says the odds are 1:N, where N = the zip code. I am fairly certain that is wrong... N does not represent the number of possible outcomes and this isn't a random draw.

**Is this even a probability question at all?** I feel like it is not, although that was never my strongest suit.

Let's assume the ZIP code is 50002.  The friend's logic is:

> there is only one possible favorable outcome out of 50,002 opportunities... the odds of your car's mileage and your zip matching was 1 in 50,002

Why assume that each turn of the odometer represents an "opportunity" (to take a photo of the odometer)?  Would it be more appropriate to use the inverse, which is that *each photo taken* represent an opportunity (that the photo might include the odometer)?

Certainly, we could say "From a collection of 1,000 photos where 30 contain a vehicle's instrument panel, the odds that any randomly selected photo contains the instrument panel are 3%, and the odds that the odometer in that photo = any given ZIP code are 1:100,000 (I'm assuming for simplicity that ZIP code is valid range(00000:99999)), so that the likelihood of any randomly selected photo might include an odometer reading matching a given ZIP code are 30/1,000 * 1/100,000, or about 1/333,333

But I'm not sure how, or even if it's possible to formulate the rhetorical above in terms of a probability statement.

Additional doubts of mine: On what timeline? At the moment the  photo was taken, no other odometer reading was possible. Your car will eventually roll over 50,002 as long as you don't wreck it. The odometer reading isn't random. It moves in one direction only.

Comment: The way we talk about probability in real life is not necessarily easy/possible to formalize in 'technical' terms. One such example is the famous https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem You need to be very careful in defining your sample space properly, and the probability of each outcome. And off the record, if your ZIP code is 50002, how on Earth would you deduce that there are only 50,002 opportunities? If your zip code were 00001, would you be the only citizen ;-) ?

Comment: Agreed @PierpaoloVivo -- specifically regarding the number of "opportunities", as the friend suggested -- it is my understanding that the friend's assumption is very much incorrect -- there may be more or fewer opportunities, but the opportunities are not dependent (I think) on the vehicle's mileage.